# OrientDB Find vertex is linked with a list of another vertex

Tags: orientdb

i am discovering OrientDB and i have a problem :

I have two vertex definition :

```
 Product
 Criterion
```

And one Edge definition:

```
 - IsRelatedToEdge
```

Thanks to IsRelatedToEdge, I can link one product to many criterion

In my example, i have populated the database with 5 products

```
 shoe-1
 shoe-2
 shoe-3
 hat-1
 hat-2
```

and 4 criterions :
     blue
     red
     hat
     shoe

Then I linked products with criterion this way:

```
 shoe-1 <=> shoe
 shoe-1 <=> blue
 shoe-2 <=> shoe
 shoe-2 <=> red
 shoe-3 <=> shoe
 shoe-3 <=> blue
 hat-1 <=> shoe
 hat-1 <=> blue
 hat-2 <=> hat
 hat-2 <=> red
```

so we have 2 blue shoe, 1 blue hat, 1 red shoe, 1 red hat.

---

### I cannot figure out how to find all blue shoes.

EDIT : I have found a 'solution' but it doesn't looks good :

```
select from Product where 
    in('IsRelatedToEdge')[name="blue"].size() = 1 and
    in('IsRelatedToEdge')[name="shoe"].size() = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the power of OrientDB lies in the graph abilities, and queries on a table/index do not really leverage this. I feel the best way to do this query is to get the shoe criterion, then get all of the products that have an edge to the criterion. From those products (ie all the shoes), you can now filter for ones that also have an edge to the blue criterion. One way to write this is as follows...

```
select * 
from (select expand(both('IsRelatedToEdge')) from Criterion where name = 'Shoe') 
let $blue_criterion = (select from Criterion where name = 'Blue')
where both('IsRelatedToEdge') contains $blue_criterion[0]
```

Taking the above thought process further though, you could consider rearranging your data for better/easier querying. For example, you could make a Hat and Shoe class that are both subclasses of Product. That way to query on shoes, you query against the Shoe vertex class only. Similarly, you can make different criterion subclass, such as Color. To get blue shoes with such a config, the query would like the following...

```
select * 
from Shoes
let $blue_criterion = (select from Color where name = 'Blue')
where both('IsRelatedToEdge') contains $blue_criterion[0]
```

You could even make more specific edges to take this a step further.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I cannot take your second solution because I wil handle a big number of criterion, and i didnt' know how much of them will be packaged.

The first solution suits me better, although I must now find how to implement it in Java and a number of indeterminate criterion :)

Answer (score 1):

After studying neRok'solutions, i came at this solutions:

```
select expand($result)
let
       $crit1 = (select expand(out('IsRelatedToEdge')) from Criterion where name='blue'),
       $crit2 = (select expand(out('IsRelatedToEdge')) from Criterion where name='shoe'),
       $result = intersect($crit1, $crit2)
```

With this kind of query, I can add another criterion.
Imagine if we have anotehr criterion named adidas and i want to have all blue adidas shoes :

```
select expand($result)
    let
           $crit1 = (select expand(out('IsRelatedToEdge')) from Criterion where name='blue'),
           $crit2 = (select expand(out('IsRelatedToEdge')) from Criterion where name='shoe'),
           $crit3 = (select expand(out('IsRelatedToEdge')) from Criterion where name='adidas'),
           $result = intersect($crit1, $crit2, $crit3)
```

Comment: Ah, very nice. I haven't done a query like that before, I will have to try it out and check the performance. It looks like it should be pretty efficient. BTW- you might not need any of the `expand()` calls within the `$crit` queries, as `out('IsRelatedToEdge')` should return a list of Product rids, which should be enough for the `intersect()` to work. This is just a hunch though, I can't test it right now.

Comment: I verify and I have to use expand, otherwise it doesn't work