# How to find vertexes by the properties of edges using "AND" in orientdb?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb3.0

I have two classes and one edge:

1. Class: `Product`
2. Class: `Parameter`
3. Edge: `ProductHasParameter` with a property `value`

**Question**: How to find all `Product` that have 2 edges `ProductHasParameter`:

- with the `value`=<SOME_VALUE_1> to `Parameter` with @rid=1
  AND
- with the `value`=<SOME_VALUE_2> to `Parameter` with @rid=2

?

Example:

[image]

**Question**: Which `Products` have Color=red AND price=1000$?

**In other words**: Which vertexes of class `Product` have 2 edges `ProductHasParameter`:

- with a property `value`=red to `Parameter` with @rid=8
  AND
- with a property `value`=1000$ to `Parameters` with @rid=12

?

Note: There is a Product with @rid=2 that doesn't have any edges at all.

I expect to get only Product with @rid=1.

In Cypher, i can write the query like this:

```
MATCH (prd:Product)-[hasParameterColor:ProductHasParameter]->(paramColor:Parameter {@rid:"8"})
MATCH (prd:Product)-[hasParameterPrice:ProductHasParameter]->(paramPrice:Parameter {@rid:"12"})
WHERE hasParameterColor.value="red" AND hasParameterPrice.value="1000$"
RETURN pr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
MATCH {class: ProductHasParameter, where:(value=1000)}.outV().outE('ProductHasParameter'){where:(value='red')}.outV(){as: cars} RETURN expand(cars);
```

MATCH {class: ProductHasParameter, where:(value=1000)} selects all ProductHasParameter edges with value 1000 (filters out any other value other than 1000)

.outV() selects all the out vertices of the edges (cars) which implies card whose value is 1000 (can be of any color)

.outE('ProductHasParameter'){where:(value='red')} selects all the out ProductHasParameter edges from the vertices (cars) that has value red, the out vertices of these edges will have value as 1000 and color as red

.outV(){as: cars} selects the vertices back (cars)

I have not tested the query so cannot say if it works but the above thought process should filter out the cars you requires.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.
I also found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31822194/11417553, but your solution is better i think

Comment: If i write query with OR:

`MATCH {class: ProductHasParameter, where:(value=1000 or value='red')}.outV(){as: cars}`
I will get duplicate in response: [@rid=1, @rid=1], because 2 nodes` satisfies condition `(value=1000 or value='red')`.
Of course, I can use `distinct` in return statement, but in that case, i will not able to traverse by the graph more. I want smth like this:
`MATCH {class: ProductHasParameter, where:(value=1000 or value='red')}.outV(){as: cars}.outE('SomeOtherEdge'){as:otherEdge}
Return otherEdge`

In the query i will get `otherEdge` twice also. It is issue(

Comment: Yes, it would be, what you are looking for is an AND condition, the logic is filter with one condition and then filter with another, you unfortunately cannot use OR because that will select both. Essentially you are looking for is an intersection of sets, this AND that

Comment: In that case, implementation of a `QueryBuilder` will be complicated in a program language, because i am forced to write completely different query for OR.
I just want to write about same OR and AND operation in query, like in SQL It is just a switch between AND and OR in `WHERE` clause, but it seems, graph database is not really suitable for this.
Anyway, thanks a lot for reply @user:3883475. You helped me